# angular format decimal to show 4 places after decimal and no comma

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

We are receiving data from a service, which includes a property called Key which holds:
1000.0000

we need to display as that, I tried:

```
{{ item.Key }}
```

but that always writes our 1000 not including the .0000.  I then tried:

```
{{inventoryItem.Key | number:4}}
```

that writes out 1,000.0000  the decimal places are good but we don't want the comma, is there another filter we can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own filter and tell it how many decimals you need:

```
app.filter('NumFilter', function() {
  return function(num, NumDecimals) {
      return num.toFixed(NumDecimals)
  }
})
```

Here's a simple application using this.

**CONTROLLER:**

```
var app = angular.module('example', []);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.inventoryItem = { key: 12345.000000 }
});

app.filter('NumFilter', function() {
  return function(num, NumDecimals) {
      return num.toFixed(NumDecimals)
  }
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="example" ng-controller="MyController">
    {{ inventoryItem.key | NumFilter:4 }}
</div>
```

Comment: @JonHarding Numbers do not inherently get commas. It is the angular filter "number" that the OP is using is what is giving it the commas. This solution will not produce commas because it is not using that filter.